# Unable to Downgrade OpenSSL from openssl-1.0.2k to openssl-1.0.1e-58 due to openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-25.el6 dependencies

Tags: centos6, openssl, yum, rpm

Due to issues with old CentOS6 machines and the Let's Encrypt root certificate that recently expired I found a solution online which involves installing a Patched version of openssl-1.0.2k from CentOS7. This is something I've done before and it always worked perfectly, however, in one specific server, as soon as I installed this version of OpenSSL, for some reason sshd threw a segmentation fault and now it doesn't start throwing this error:

```
key_curve_nid_to_name: unsupported EC curve nid -1
/etc/init.d/sshd: line 128: 29710 Segmentation fault      $SSHD $OPTIONS
```

So I just tried Downgrading OpenSSL to the previous version, but since openssl1.0.2k now uses a seperate package (openssl-libs), when I try to downgrade I just get this error

```
[root@ ~]# yum downgrade openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Downgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-58.el6_10 will be a downgrade
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-21.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                                         Version                                                 Repository                                     Size
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Downgrading:
 openssl                                       x86_64                                       1.0.1e-58.el6_10                                        updates                                       1.5 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Downgrade     1 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.5 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                              | 1.5 MB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.10.hmac from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/.libssl.so.10.hmac from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libaep.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libatalla.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcapi.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libchil.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcswift.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libgmp.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libnuron.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libpadlock.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libsureware.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libubsec.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64
```

Manually removing openssl-libs doesn't work either cause pretty much everything depends on it, including yum.

Does anyone know how I can ignore this dependency while downgrading? Or perhaps install the old version while ignoring if a newer version is installed?